# Calling programs inside a loop

Tags: bash

I have code like this

```
 Alien=(misterX 3010 6400 9920 12750 3010 6400 9920 12750 9920)
 Opponent=(misterY 3090 6450 10020 12820 10020 12820 3090 6450 9910)

for (( y=1 ; y<${#Alien[@]} ; y++ )); do
    echo "scale=2;(${Opponent[$y]}-${Alien[$y]})/1000" | bc | sed -e 's/^\./0./g' -e 's/^-\./-0./g'

done
```

With this i can easly asign output to array

```
 for (( y=1 ; y<${#Alien[@]} ; y++ )); do
    Wynik+=($(echo "scale=2;(${Opponent[$y]}-${Alien[$y]})/1000" | bc | sed -e 's/^\./0./g' -e 's/^-\./-0./g'))

done

echo ${Wynik[@]}
```

But this is slow so after googling i have much faster version like

```
(
echo "scale=2;"
for (( y=1 ; y<${#Alien[@]} ; y++ )); do
    echo "(${Opponent[$y]}-${Alien[$y]})/1000"

done
 ) | bc | sed -e 's/^\./0./g' -e 's/^-\./-0./g'
```

Partially i understand how it works, but can't find a way to move output to array. Only way i found is

```
 (
echo "scale=2;"
for (( y=1 ; y<${#Alien[@]} ; y++ )); do
    echo "(${Opponent[$y]}-${Alien[$y]})/1000"

done
 ) | bc | sed -e 's/^\./0./g' -e 's/^-\./-0./g' > filename
 Wynik+=($(cat filename))

 echo ${Wynik[@]}
```

Still faster, at least for ssd, but this is just not right, i know this. How i should do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your expression in `( $( ... ) )` and assign it to variable.

```
Wynik=( $( (
echo "scale=2;"
for (( y=1 ; y<${#Alien[@]} ; y++ )); do
    echo "(${Opponent[$y]}-${Alien[$y]})/1000"
done
) | bc | sed -e 's/^\./0./g' -e 's/^-\./-0./g' ) )
```

Syntax `$( ... )` is evaluates the expression and additional pair of parentheses around everything denote an array.